# Minus Plus sign on soft keyboard in android app

Tags: android, unicode, keyboard, custom-controls

I've created a custom keyboard from scratch and it works fine but I have 2 problems with 2 keys.

C - clear key, which when the user presses on clears the text
+/- - adding/removing minus before the number.

All the keys work fine with the android code and when I looked at the SDK example, they were using Unicode (not the Android code). It works fine in the example but in my app it doesn't do anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="25%p" 
android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:verticalGap="0px" 
android:keyHeight="40dip"
>

<Row>
    <Key android:codes="14" android:keyLabel="7" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="15" android:keyLabel="8"/>
    <Key android:codes="16" android:keyLabel="9"/>
    <Key android:codes="67"  android:keyIcon="@drawable/keyboard_delete"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/keyboard_delete"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>

</Row>

<Row>
    <Key android:codes="11" android:keyLabel="4" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="12" android:keyLabel="5"/>
    <Key android:codes="13" android:keyLabel="6"/>
    <Key android:codes="" android:keyLabel="C" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>

<Row>
    <Key android:codes="8" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="9" android:keyLabel="2"/>
    <Key android:codes="10" android:keyLabel="3"/>
    <Key android:codes="69" android:keyLabel="±" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="7" android:keyLabel="0" android:keyWidth="50%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="."/>
</Row>
</Keyboard>
```

Thank you 
Niro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ... I haven't found a solution strait from build in keyboard.
I don't think there is code that support +/- or clear.
Iv'e solved it through the Listener

```
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] arg1) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
long eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime,
    KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, primaryCode, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE);

 if(primaryCode==177)
 {
 pressedC_Button();
 }
else
 if(primaryCode==241)
{
  pressedNegative_button();
}

dispatchKeyEvent(event);

}
```

Thanks